# Nvidia driver cannot load on GeForce 2080Ti

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 20.04, xorg

I am trying to get Ubuntu 20.04 running on a computer (desktop) with a GeForce 2080Ti  and I had no luck with various versions of the nvidia drivers.

I started with a complete ubuntu reinstall (erase disk) and install the driver version coming with the 20.04 (currently with the driver 440, which is good for this card).

However, it does not work at all :

nvidia-smi
--> No devices were found.

In /var/log/Xorg.0.log
--> (EE) Failed to initialize the NVIDIA GPU at PCI:7:0:0.

dmesg
--> NVRM: GPU 0000:07/00.0: RmInitAdapter failed!

====
Other info that could help:

- I have a GUI when I prime-select intel
- Secure boot is disabled
- nouveau is blacklisted

Thanks for help,

Comment: I continued to look for solutions... I have added mem_encrypt=off but I still get the very same output. Any ideas someone? Could it be a hardware problem?

Comment: did you solve it ?

Comment: Nope. Most likely hardware issue (same problem under windows).